# Интерфейс для python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, selenium, gui

У меня есть *инстаграм бот* написанный на `selenium`. В *Qt Designer* я сделал для него интерфейс, но не могу его никак подключить.

Как мне в переменные бота вывести значения из элементов интерфейса по типу функции авторизации?

В файле находятся два класса один класс это бот, второй класс это интерфейс на *PyQt5*.

```
# username = input('Введите ваш логин: ')
# password = input('Введите ваш пороль: ')
class InstagramBot():
  username = pyqtsignal(str)
  password = pyqtsignal(str)
  def __init__(self,username,password):
      self.username = username
      self.password = password
      # options = Options()
      # options.add_argument("--headless")
      self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()

  def close_browser(self):

      self.browser.close()
      self.browser.quit()

  def login(self):
      browser = self.browser
      browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
      time.sleep(random.randrange(4 ,6))

      username_input = browser.find_element_by_name("username") 
      username_input.clear()
      username_input.send_keys(username)

      time.sleep(5)
      password_input = browser.find_element_by_name("password") 
      password_input.clear()
      password_input.send_keys(password)

      password_input = 
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main
    /article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div/div[3]/button/div").click()
    time.sleep(10)

class GUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    QtWidgets.QTabWidget.__init__(self)
    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.login)
    self.bot = InstagramBot()

  def login(self):
      InstagramBot.login()
      username = self.ui.lineEdit.text()
      password = self.ui.lineEdit_2.text()
      self.ui.lineEdit.clear()
      self.ui.lineEdit_2.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     mywin = GUI()
     mywin.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Добавьте минимальный пример, чтобы можно было с ним поиграться. А так, научитесь из виджета получать значения, обрабатывать клики и т.п. После, для этих событий передавайте значения боту из виджета

Comment: я знаю как это сделать , но не могу связать эти два класса

Comment: возможно просто мое плохое понимание ООП не дает мне реализовать это ....

Comment: Бот на селениуме открывайте в отдельном потоке. Связь между классами сделайте через сигналы

Comment: @gil9red я добавил код который нужно связать между собой , чтоб из данные из lineEdit записывались в переменные username и password а затем selenium использовал их для авторизации

Comment: Если `InstagramBot` не будет запущен в отдельном потоке, то он будет выполнять в главном потоке, и его действия, типа sleep, поиска, загрузки будет останавливать работу главного потока, а из-за этого окно будет фризиться

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118731/discussion-between-mimoza23-and-gil9red).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Накидал [пример работы](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c1a85c33cd10e9342daf93a1ff4680e691d2e52f/selenium__examples/PyQt5_with_selenium.py#L42) [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) и [pyqt5](/questions/tagged/pyqt5) на примере поиска в stackoverflow.

Главное:

- `Selenium` запущен в отдельном потоке и связь с ним сделана через сигналы `about_search_result` и `about_change_title`
- Нужно помнить, что код в потоке выполняется только в методе `run` и пока метод `run` запущен, поток будет жить
- Виджет соединен с потоком в: `self.bot_thread.about_search_result.connect(self.on_search_result)` и `self.bot_thread.about_change_title.connect(self.setWindowTitle)`
- Чтобы selenium был спрятан нужно раскомментировать строку `options.add_argument('--headless')`

Код:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QHBoxLayout, QPushButton, QTextBrowser
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal

# pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


URL = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com'


class StackOverFlowBotThread(QThread):
    about_search_result = pyqtSignal(str, str)
    about_change_title = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.is_running = False

        options = Options()
        # options.add_argument('--headless')

        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)

        self._search = None

    def search(self, text: str):
        self._search = text

    def run(self):
        self.is_running = True

        self.driver.get(URL)
        print(f'Title: "{self.driver.title}"')
        self.about_change_title.emit(self.driver.title)

        try:
            # Чтобы поток не завершился
            while self.is_running:
                if self._search:
                    search_el = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#search .s-input__search')
                    search_el.clear()
                    search_el.send_keys(self._search + Keys.RETURN)

                    # Даем время прогрузиться результату
                    time.sleep(1)
                    self.about_change_title.emit(self.driver.title)

                    for result_el in self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.result-link a[href]'):
                        title = result_el.text.strip()
                        url = urljoin(URL, result_el.get_attribute('href'))
                        self.about_search_result.emit(title, url)

                    # Поиск уже выполнен
                    self._search = None

                time.sleep(0.05)

        finally:
            self.driver.quit()

    def quit(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.is_running = False

        super().quit()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.search = QLineEdit('gil9red')
        self.search.returnPressed.connect(self.on_search)

        self.button_search = QPushButton('Search')
        self.button_search.clicked.connect(self.on_search)

        self.result = QTextBrowser()
        self.result.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

        self.bot_thread = StackOverFlowBotThread()
        self.bot_thread.about_search_result.connect(self.on_search_result)
        self.bot_thread.about_change_title.connect(self.setWindowTitle)
        self.bot_thread.start()

        layout_search = QHBoxLayout()
        layout_search.addWidget(self.search)
        layout_search.addWidget(self.button_search)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(layout_search)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.result)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def on_search(self):
        self.result.clear()

        text = self.search.text()
        self.bot_thread.search(text)

    def on_search_result(self, title, url):
        self.result.append(f'<a href="{url}">{title}</a>')

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.bot_thread.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.resize(800, 600)
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

---

Результат работы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо вам большое , попробую разобраться

Comment: @Mimoza23, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)